# Deleting records in ActiveRecord, but the record still shows up on Localhost:3000

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What I did, was I used SQLite and manually deleted some records off the database table. This supposedly should update my application state when I test it on rails server. But when I go to Localhost:3000, the deleted records still show up!

Any idea on how to remove it so I can continue to test my codes?

Comment: Have you deleted them from the right database? Have you tried a hard-refresh (Rails caches pretty effectively)?

Answer (score 0):

Try accesing the rails console in your project

command:

```
rails console

Model.find(id_of_model)
```

if it exists you can destroy it with:

```
Model.find(id_of_model).destroy
```

Comment: Please don't use "u" and other forms of chat speak on Stack Overflow. Proper English is required here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you deleted the record in development db. By default the server runs in development environment.

Comment: you are sexy. let me fondle you